# Apache2 - how to track what script is causing max cpu on all 4 cores

Tags: apache

Apache noob here.  I have a virtualbox instance with debian squeeze installed and apache.  I'm seeing all 4 of my cores max out for about 10 minuets then it goes away.  This is happening a few times per week. When I'm able to load top I can see apache processes maxed out.

/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

When I check the access log I'm not seeing a huge amount of traffic.  I installed mod_evasive last week thinking they might have been a ddos or bot hammering on login pages but I can't see that in the logs.  I'm suspecting there might be some bad php code somewhere.  How would I go about tracing where that might be?

The web server is hosting about 4 wordpress sites for a small business and another php application with about 10 users.

I've ensured i've updated debian.  I'm running on the latest wordpress.